# How to initialize cells with UITableViewController's new behavior in terms of cell reusing

Tags: ios, uitableview

It's been a while that I haven't coded iOS, and I'm witnessing some new behavior and would like to know how it works.

It used to be that `cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath]` would return a cell **or not**, but the code examples that I'm seeing now lack the initialization part:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [MyCellClass new];//and I think somehow registering the cell with the identifier
    //Some code here, for example:
    //[cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Is it going to do these initializations every time now, without checking the existence of cell?

Edit: more details about my use case:
My cell has a Nib file and I'm using the new `[[self tableView] registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"cell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"]` in my `ViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`. My `ViewController` is not present in any Nib/StoryBoard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` is guaranteed to return a cell, and always has been (it was added in iOS 6).

You're remembering `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` which was used prior to iOS 6, which did not have the same guarantee. The new API is much nicer to use :)

Comment: I see. Now what is the best practice for installing ControlEvent listeners? at every `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, one should call `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`? (Considering that in my use case it should be done programatically. The cell and controller are not in the same nib/storyboard)

Comment: To tell if a row's been tapped (presumably that's what you're trying to do..?), implement tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: in your table view controller.

Comment: I'm trying to detect if a UIButton inside the cell has been tapped

Comment: Try hooking up the button's action in IB. Target your table view controller, for example.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, they are not in the same storyboard

Comment: Then target your UITableViewCell subclass, as another example.

Answer (score 1):

When using `registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:` cell creation is taken care of automatically.

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:):

> Prior to calling the *dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:* method of the collection view, you must use this method or the *registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:* method to tell the collection view how to create a new cell of the given type. If a cell of the specified type is not currently in a reuse queue, the collection view uses the provided information to create a new cell object automatically.